# MySQL WorkBench EER diagram dimensions are terrible

Tags: entity-relationship, mysql-workbench

I am using MYSQL workbench to generate an EER diagram, and to the best of my knowledge, one can not control the dimensions of the canvas, only the size in number of pages. This has the result that you get a huge amount of white space around your diagram, making it nearly unusable. Why anyone would design it this way is beyond me. There are a lot of questions which ask how to crop a pdf, but they are either more complicated (ie. crop to a certain dimension, or crop and output to different format and ratio) or they do not preserve the image quality, or they just plain do not work. My question therefore is this:

[image]

**How does one create or convert an EER diagram using MySQL Workbench such that there are no white borders AND the image quality is preserved?**

Note I asked the question here as it pertains to databasing, but apologies if it is in the wrong place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like what you are after is a way to limit the output of an image export to a relatively small area, so that it fits nicely in another document. Several options are possible:

1) Export as png and simply cut off the unwanted parts. Depending on the further usage this might be good enough.

2) Export as SVG and use any of the SVG editors to limit the image size to the wanted area only. Then convert it to the format you need in your target document.

3) Set a paper size in the model that encompasses the content as close as possible. E.g. the `statement` paper type is quite small. Then rearrange your objects. Resize them if you need larger ones. By setting a larger font (via Preferences) you should be able to make the entire appearence larger. Then export as PDF.

Comment: Zoom level of what, WorkBench diagram or PDF? Also, I don't think zoom level affects the actual page dimensions

Comment: Sorry, misread your question. I'm not sure what you are after actually. You have a very small diagram. Adding 10 pages won't make it bigger, but just add empty room around it. Is your wish to make the tables each like an A4 page in size? Printing the diagram will result in closely the same size on paper/pdf as it is on screen (with both 100% zoom level). You can play with the paper size, but I'm not sure this will change much.

Comment: I'm including the PDF in a LaTex document, so if there is a great deal of whitespace around it, the image will look very small

Comment: I was using all the time the option "Print to PDF" and that option was not configuring the page properly (like how I wanted, in A3 format).

The only way I was finding to print the document was to connect the printer directly and use normal print.

Problem: my printer doesn't print A3.

Solution: go to a printing shop that prints A3, try and install workbench there or connect my computer and print.

Action, after going to 3 different shops, going through the various problems, needed to find a way to print in a format they would understand.

Thank you man!!